# Windows Form's не растягивается под конкретное окно c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, разработка-игр, gdi

Вообщем, сразу скажу, что изучаю программирование относительно не давно. Пишу хак (для себя, для опыта) на c# для quake 3 arena, а конкретно CPMA. 
Перейдем к проблеме. 
Все хорошо компилируется. Указываю название окна игры (CNQ3), на которое при нажатии на чекбокс будет наложено поверх прозрачное окно, в котором буду в будущем ESP боксы и прочая информация об игроках. Вот тут я столкнулся с такой проблемой. На обычном ванильном квейке все работает хорошо:
[image: Работает на обычном квейке идеально.]

А вот как выходит на том квейке, который мне нужен:
[image: Не отображается корректно]
Мне нужно, чтобы на втором окне форма разворачивалась на всю площадь игры. А она просто тусуется в верхнем правом углу окна. Возможно дело в названии окна? Окно называется: CNQ3 и в коде указанно точно так-же. Понятия не имею в чем может быть проблема. Кусок кода снизу. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace q3_hack
{
    public partial class FormOverlay : Form
    {
        RECT rect;
        public const string WINDOW_NAME = "CNQ3";
        IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WINDOW_NAME);


        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }


        Graphics g;
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        public FormOverlay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormOverlay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Wheat;
            this.TopMost = true;
            //this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Скрывает визуально окно оверлея.

            int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);


            GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
            this.Size = new Size(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
            this.Top = rect.top;
            this.Left = rect.left;

        }

        private void FormOverlay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawRectangle(myPen, 50, 50, 60, 60);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно `GetWindowRect` вам возвращает что-то не то. Смотрие в отладке, что именно. Судя по скриншоту, координаты возможно правильные, а вот размеры - нет.

Comment: Что возвращает `GetWindowRect` (и что при этом записывается в структуру `rect`)? Какое значение в этот момент имеет `handle`?